# how to get scroll position in blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

i'm trying to get the scroll position from EventArgs but it doesn't give me the required information of the scroll position
so is JS only way, also I tried the @onwheel event and it works fine but it only works when I'm using the mouse wheel

```cs
    @inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime
    
      <div @onscroll="Scroll"  class="p-4 border-2 border-gray-200 border-dashed rounded-lg dark:border-gray-700 chat-area responsive-chat-area">
         @ChatContent
      </div>
    
    @code {
          
        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment ChatContent { get; set; }
     
        private async void Scroll(EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", eventArgs);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your requirement, if you want to know how to get the scroll position for the Div, I suggest you could use JS to get it.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

Put a JS like below inside the index.html :

```
   <script>
       // JS file or script tag
       function getScrollPosition(elementId) {
           let element = document.getElementById(elementId);
   
           return {
               scrollTop: element.scrollTop,
               scrollLeft: element.scrollLeft,
               scrollHeight: element.scrollHeight,
               clientHeight: element.clientHeight
           };
       }
   </script>
```

Component codes：

```
 @inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime
 
<div id="chatArea" @onscroll="@Scroll" style="border:1px dashed red;height:100px;width:200px;overflow:auto">
    In my younger and more vulnerable years my father gave me some advice that I've been turning over in my mind ever since.
    <br><br>
    'Whenever you feel like criticizing anyone,' he told me, just remember that all the people in this world haven't had the advantages that you've had.'


</div>

<h1>position:@position</h1>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChatContent { get; set; }


    public double position;


    private async void Scroll()
    {
        // Using IJSRuntime to call the JavaScript function and pass the element's ID
        var scrollPosition = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<ScrollData>("getScrollPosition", "chatArea");

        position = scrollPosition.ScrollTop;
    }

    // Define a C# class to hold the scroll position data
    public class ScrollData
    {
        public double ScrollTop { get; set; }
        public double ScrollLeft { get; set; }
        public double ScrollHeight { get; set; }
        public double ClientHeight { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: btw, the lack of information in event arguments is a know issue.. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/7357